# Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

How can I get the selected text (not the selected value) from a **drop-down list** in jQuery?

Comment: Just my two cents: An "ASP" drop-down is no special; it's just good old HTML. :-)

Comment: One can refer this article: http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/selecting-dropdown-element-using-javascript-or-jquery/

Comment: for vanilla  javascript way, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5947/32453

Comment: Just $(this).prop('selected', true);

replaced .att to .prop it worked for all browsers

Comment: $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();

Answer (score 4027, accepted):

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
```

Comment: I think this should be
`$("#yourdropdownid").children("option").filter(":selected").text()`
since is() returns a boolean of whether the object matches the selector or not.

Comment: I second the comment about is() returning a boolen; alternatively, use the following small alteration: 
$('#yourdropdownid').children("option:selected").text();

Comment: `$('select').children(':selected')` is the fastest way: http://jsperf.com/get-selected-option-text

Comment: And if have scape caracteres like `\n \t` you can add `.trim()` getting like this: `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text().trim();`

Answer (score 290):

Try this:

```
$("#myselect :selected").text();
```

For an ASP.NET dropdown you can use the following selector:

```
$("[id*='MyDropDownId'] :selected")
```

Answer (score 238):

The answers posted here, for example,

```
$('#yourdropdownid option:selected').text();
```

didn't work for me, but this did:

```
$('#yourdropdownid').find('option:selected').text();
```

It is possibly an older version of jQuery.

Answer (score 120):

If you already have the dropdownlist available in a variable, this is what works for me:

```
$("option:selected", myVar).text()
```

The other answers on this question helped me, but ultimately the jQuery forum thread *[$(this + "option:selected").attr("rel") option selected is not working in IE](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/this-option-selected-attr-rel-option-selected-is-not-working-in-ie)* helped the most.

Update: fixed the above link

Comment: ```

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                var value = $("#myselection option:selected");
                alert(value.text());
            });
        });
    </script>

```

<br>

Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-using-jquery/

Answer (score 81):

This works for me

```
$("#dropdownid").change(function() {
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

If the element created dynamically

```
$(document).on("change", "#dropdownid", function() {
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

Answer (score 69):

```
$("option:selected", $("#TipoRecorde")).text()
```

Answer (score 56):

This works for me:

```
$('#yourdropdownid').find('option:selected').text();
```

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) version: 1.9.1

Answer (score 54):

`$("#DropDownID").val()`  will give the selected index value.

Comment: Not exactly the answer to the question, but was useful for me. The question wants the selected text.

Comment: @Neeraj, thank you for the answer.  I discovered that val() != text() and in case when you have more then one value you will get something like....
'\n\tBYELORUSSIAN\n\tCATALAN\n\tCHINESESIMPLIFIED\n\tCHINESETRADITIONAL\n\tCROATIAN\n\tCZECH\n\tDANISH\n\tDUTCH\n\tESPERANTO\n\tESTONIAN\n\tFINNISH\n\tFRENCH\n\tGALICIAN\n\tGERMA'

Answer (score 44):

For the text of the selected item, use:

```
$('select[name="thegivenname"] option:selected').text();
```

For the value of the selected item, use:

```
$('select[name="thegivenname"] option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 41):

Use this

```
const select = document.getElementById("yourSelectId");

const selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;
const selectedValue = select.value;
const selectedText = select.options[selectedIndex].text;
```

Then you get your selected value and text inside `selectedValue` and `selectedText`.

Answer (score 35):

Various ways

```
1. $("#myselect option:selected").text();

2. $("#myselect :selected").text();

3. $("#myselect").children(":selected").text();

4. $("#myselect").find(":selected").text();
```

Answer (score 32):

```
$("#dropdownID").change(function(){
  alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
});
```

Answer (score 31):

```
var someName = "Test";

$("#<%= ddltest.ClientID %>").each(function () {
    $('option', this).each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == someName) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected')
        };
    });
});
```

That will help you to get right direction. Above code is fully tested if you need further help let me know.

Answer (score 20):

For those who are using [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) lists and don't want to use the long generated id, this will work:

```
var e = $('select[title="IntenalFieldName"] option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 20):

This code worked for me.

```
$("#yourdropdownid").children("option").filter(":selected").text();
```

Comment: Works too! And if have scape caracteres like `\n \t` you can add `.trim()` getting like this: `$("#yourdropdownid").children("option").filter(":selected").text().trim();`

Answer (score 17):

```
 $("#selectID option:selected").text();
```

Instead of `#selectID` you can use any jQuery selector, like `.selectClass` using class.

As mentioned in the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).

*The :selected selector works for <option> elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio inputs; use `:checked` for them.*

**.text()** As per the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

*Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.*

So you can take text from any HTML element using the `.text()` method.

Refer the documentation for a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 16):

```
$("select[id=yourDropdownid] option:selected").text()
```

This works fine

Answer (score 16):

```
$("#dropdown").find(":selected").text();


$("#dropdown :selected").text();
```

`$("#dropdown option:selected").text();`

```
$("#dropdown").children(":selected").text();
```

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
$var = jQuery("#dropdownid option:selected").val();
   alert ($var);
```

Or to get the text of the option, use `text()`:

```
$var = jQuery("#dropdownid option:selected").text();
   alert ($var);
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 14):

Simply try the following code.

```
var text= $('#yourslectbox').find(":selected").text();
```

it returns the text of the selected option.

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#id').find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 13):

Select Text and selected value on dropdown/select change event in jQuery

```
$("#yourdropdownid").change(function() {
    console.log($("option:selected", this).text()); //text
    console.log($(this).val()); //value
})
```

Answer (score 13):

For getting selected value use

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

and for getting selected item text use this line:

```
$("#dropDownId option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var e = document.getElementById("dropDownId");
var div = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
('#yourdropdownid').find(':selected').text();
```

Answer (score 8):

the following worked for me:

```
$.trim($('#dropdownId option:selected').html())
```

Answer (score 7):

In sibling case

```
<a class="uibutton confirm addClient" href="javascript:void(0);">ADD Client</a>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter client name" style="margin: 5px;float: right" class="clientsearch large" />
<select class="mychzn-select clientList">
  <option value="">Select Client name....</option>
  <option value="1">abc</option>
</select>


 /*jQuery*/
 $(this).siblings('select').children(':selected').text()
```

Answer (score 7):

This work for me:

```
$("#city :selected").text();
```

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2

Answer (score 6):

```js
$(function () {
  alert('.val() = ' + $('#selectnumber').val() + '  AND  html() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').html() + '  AND .text() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <select id="selectnumber">
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
          <option value="3">three</option>
          <option value="4">four</option>
        </select>

      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Click to see OutPut Screen]

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
dropdown.selectedOptions[0].text
```

```js
function read() {
  console.log( dropdown.selectedOptions[0].text );
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
<button onclick="read()">read</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a pure-JS approach.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the result as a list, then use:

```
x=[];
$("#list_id").children(':selected').each(function(){x.push($(this).text());})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#dropdownid option:selected").text();
```

if you use asp.net and write

```
<Asp:dropdownlist id="ddl" runat="Server" />
```

then you should use

```
$('#<%=ddl.Clientid%> option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

For multi-selects:

```
$("#yourdropdownid :selected").map(function(i, v) { return $.trim($(v).text()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below line

```
$(this).prop('selected', true);
```

replaced .att to .prop it worked for all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#dropdownid").change(function(el) {
    console.log(el.value);
});
```

Or you can use this

```
$("#dropdownid").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```