# jQuery: Selecting an item in a drop down list using the text value

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, what is the easiest way to select an item in a drop down list using the text value.

For example, I have drop down list that has a list of states. And I have the text value of “PA”. I want to make “PA” be the selected value.  What is the best way to do this using jQuery. I have been doing Google searches for hours and I cannot find an example to this question.

Note each item in the drop down list has a numeric key.  And I know that $(#ddlStates).val(key) will select the value I want. However, I do not have the key only the test (“PA”)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be 100% sure on the match you can do this:

```
$("#ddlStates option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == "PA";
}).attr('selected', true);
```

What will probably work for your scenario is the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, less safe in others is just:

```
$("#ddlStates option:contains('PA')").attr('selected', true);
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/3y6xG/), you wouldn't want to use this in other cases because it would match a substring, but since you have states, presumably all 2 letters it will work here.  For other cases you can use the first method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myselect :selected").text();
```

see this post [Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist)