# Get the selected value in a dropdown using jQuery.

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My HTML is below. I need to get the selected value (`Scheduled`) using the 
`<select>` tag. How can this be done using jQuery?

```
<select id="availability" style="display: none;">
  <option value="Available">Available</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option value="Unavailable">Unavailable</option>
</select>
```

I did a `jQuery("#availability")` to get the select tag, but I do not know how to get the selected options' value.

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery("#availability option:selected").val();
```

Or to get the text of the option, use `text()`:

```
jQuery("#availability option:selected").text();
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: I think jQuery can recognize which is selected, even without specifying the selector option:selected. This would work too: $("#availability").val();

Comment: Can try too `$("select[id='availability'] option:selected").val();`

Answer (score 11):

The above solutions didn't work for me. Here is what I finally came up with:

```
$( "#ddl" ).find( "option:selected" ).text();           // Text
$( "#ddl" ).find( "option:selected" ).prop("value");    // Value
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#availability option:selected").text();
```

This will give you the text value of your dropdown list.  You can also use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) depending on what you're looking to get.  Follow the link to the jQuery documentation and examples.

Answer (score 5):

I have gone through all the answers provided above.
This is the easiest way which I used to get the selected value from the drop down list

`$('#searchType').val() // for the value`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it works for `val()` but not `text()`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#availability').find('option:selected').val() // For Value 
$('#availability').find('option:selected').text() // For Text
or 
$('#availability option:selected').val() // For Value 
$('#availability option:selected').text() // For Text
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you maybe explain what the code does?

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys i am using this technique to get the values from the selected **dropdown** list and it is working like charm.

```
var methodvalue = $("#method option:selected").val();
```