# Getting the selected option with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this;

```
<select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>First</option>
    <option value='2'>Second </option>
    <option value='3'>Third </option>
</select>
```

i want to specifically get the option selected and put it an a variable, then alert what's in the variable.
I tried

```
var value = $("#list option:selected").text();
alert(value);
```

but its not working :(
Ps: i need the selected value in a variable. 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/Guteh/1/ You must not be including jQuery correctly, or something.

Comment: but it's not alerting the value?

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your document? Can you explain what's "not working" about it?

Comment: yh <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#list').change(function() {
  var value = $("#list option:selected").text();
alert(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Y9WT/