# Get the value of a dropdown in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down that has an 'ID, Name' Pair.

Example

Jon Miller
Jim Smith
Jen Morsin

Jon MIller has ID of 101
Jim Smith has ID of 102
Jen Morsin has ID of 103

When I do the followng:

```
var arNames = $('#Crd').val()
```

and I select Jon Miller, I get 101. I'd like to get Jon Miller though.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist

Answer (score 211, accepted):

`$('#Crd').val()` will give you the selected value of the drop down element. Use this to get the selected options text.

```
$('#Crd option:selected').text();
```

Comment: $('#Crd option:selected').text() or $('#Crd option:selected').val(), .text gives you the value of the displayed text, not the value

Comment: $('#Crd option:selected').val();
for value

Answer (score 14):

The best way is to use:

```
$("#yourid option:selected").text();
```

Depending on the requirement, you could also use this way:

```
var v = $("#yourid").val();
$("#yourid option[value="+v+"]").text()
```

Answer (score 6):

This has worked for me!

```
$('#selected-option option:selected').val()
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a `<select>`, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gets the 'value' of the selected `<option>`. If it doesn't have a `value`, it may fallback to the `id`. Put the value you want it to return in the `value` attribute of each `<option>`

*Edit:* See comments for clarification on what `value` actually is (not necessarily equal to the `value` attribute).

Comment: Just a clarification, .val() returns the *live value property* not the HTML attribute value.

Comment: Correct. However there is no practical difference in this case as the OP does not seem to want to change the `value`s at any point.

Comment: `.val() gets the 'value' attribute of the selected <option>`, like I said: just clarifying.

Comment: What if I need the index or id rather than the text?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var text = $('#YourDropdownId').find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
$("#<%=dropDownId.ClientID%>").children("option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var sal = $('.selectSal option:selected').eq(0).val();
```

`selectSal` is a class.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out ... in a `select` box, the `.val()` attribute will give you the value of the selected option. If the selected option does not have a value attribute it will default to the display value of the option (which is what the examples on the [jQuery documentation of `.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) show.

you want to use `.text()` of the selected option:

`$('#Crd option:selected').text()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.leave_response').on('change', function() {
    var responseId = $(this).val();
    console.log(responseId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
    <select class="leave_response" name="leave">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id and hold into a variable and pass the variable where ever you want.

> var temp = $('select[name=ID Name]').val();

Comment: $('select[name=ID Name] option:selected').val();

This One Also Work

Answer (score 0):

You can have text value of #Crd in its variable .

```
$(document).on('click', '#Crd', function () {
     var Crd = $( "#Crd option:selected" ).text();
});
```