# jquery show different value from the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I having a dropdown like this

```
<select name="phoneCallingCode" id="phoneCallingCode" class="input">
   <option value="93">Afghanistan (+ 93)</option>
   <option value="355">Albania (+ 355)</option>
   <option value="213">Algeria (+ 213)</option>
</select>
```

when I select a value Afghanistan (+ 93), I just want to show +93 in the display, it that possible through jquery.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Take value and concatenate it! `var result = "+" + $("#phoneCallingCode").val()`!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978328/jquery-dropdown-get-value

Comment: @Dhaval Marthak I have to show in display

Comment: @Suganthan What do you mean by display? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Dhaval Marthak please see the edit

Comment: u mean if u select afganishtan , Textbox should have +93 correct?

Comment: Please clarify Question.You didnt tell where you want drop down value and many things .Create fiddle

Comment: Here in ur dropdown Afghanistan (+ 93) , You already have +93 ,So what u want when anyone changes from Algeria to Afganishtan ? You want double value like Afghanistan (+ 93) + 93 ?

Comment: No functionality wise no issues, I am trying to accomplish the User experience, In the dropdown I need "Afghanistan (+ 93)" while select I just need to show "93"

Comment: so it will be double  +6721  , +6721 what do u think?

Comment: No, I 'll be double, but the requirement is to show only the callingcode, it is double for developers but not for user

Comment: And if I don't having that value there, again I have to go for regex to split everything, that is a overhead

Comment: Do u really think , that The arrow can be replaced with Text? :) Its not possible , as its HTML element by default .Max to max u can give style to arrow. :) NOT POSSIBLE

Comment: I am indicating that textarea of dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Okay from my understanding you want to show number when anyone selects country in drop down.

So you can do something like this:

```
$('#phoneCallingCode').change(function() {

    $("option:selected", this).text($("option:selected", this).val());

});
```

But remember this will change selected option text too, so user may have hard time finding country name again.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NyHts/

Comment: you are right, but have to retain the existing value in drop down

Comment: No you can't do like that. you will have to store text of selected option somewhere before changing it to its value. Let me see if i can provide functionality like that.

Comment: I am also trying to accomplish

Comment: @Abhishek , did you see OP's Edit :) ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi yes i did, May be have to use data-text attribute to show original value when select box is open and when closed show value.

Comment: @Abhishek , he wants to replace Arrow with Text :)  Comeon its HTML element.We cant override their elements. Like we cant give Checkbox functionality to Radio button

Comment: @PratikJoshi and obviously jquery don't have functions for something like on open/close select boxes.

Comment: @Abhishek i flagged question as low quality and Unclear what OP asking . He is WASTING Developer's time , by changing requirements and telling vague question which is not possible to achieve

Comment: Yes, thanks. absolutely question is not clear. Flagging it too as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Xc4e/1/)

Code

```
//For starting of page
  valNum=$("#phoneCallingCode").val();
   $("#nmbr").val(valNum);

$("#phoneCallingCode").change(function(){
   valNum=$(this).val();
   $("#nmbr").val(valNum);
});
```

It means,Get value of selected Drop down option and Set the value of Textbox by the value in valNum variable.

And when document is ready , u need contry Number in textbox so The code //For starting of page

Comment: textbox in the sense not in separate textbox, I want in the same component

Comment: In the question, separate textbox is to enter phone number

Comment: You want country number in same dropdown?

Comment: @Suganthan , then what is problem with Abhishek's solution

Comment: Please see Abhishek's answer, but their I want to retain the existing dropdown

Comment: Please tell What u want in Dropdown as value when i select Afgahnishan ? edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
$('#phoneCallingCode').change(function() {
    $("#ShowNumber").val("+" +$("#phoneCallingCode option:selected").val())
});
```

HTML

```
<select name="phoneCallingCode" id="phoneCallingCode" class="input">
   <option value="93">Afghanistan (+ 93)</option>
   <option value="355">Albania (+ 355)</option>
   <option value="213">Algeria (+ 213)</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="ShowNumber"/>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NyHts/2/)

Comment: textbox in the sense not in separate textbox, I want in the same component

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for better understand.

Comment: This answer is exactly similar to Pratik one.

Comment: @Abhishek I have not seen that Pratik posted same answer.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal  , did you see OP's Edit :) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#phoneCallingCode').change(function(){
        var selectedOptionVal = $(this).val();
        var temp = "[value='"+selectedOptionVal+"']";
        var selected = $(temp).html();
        if (selected.indexOf("(+") != -1) {
            var selectedString     = selected.substring(selected.indexOf("(+")+1,selected.length-1);
            $(temp).html(selectedString);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task using HTML5 data attribute as below:

```
<select name="phoneCallingCode" id="phoneCallingCode" class="input" onclick="resetPhoneCallingCode()" onblur="displayContryCode();">
    <option value="93" data-text="Afghanistan (+ 93)">Afghanistan (+ 93)</option>
    <option value="355" data-text="Albania (+ 355)">Albania (+ 355)</option>
    <option value="213" data-text="Algeria (+ 213)">Algeria (+ 213)</option>
</select>

<script>
    function resetPhoneCallingCode() {
        $("#phoneCallingCode option").each(function () {
            $(this).text($(this).attr('data-text'));
        });
    }
    function displayContryCode() {
        $("#phoneCallingCode option:selected").text("+" + $("#phoneCallingCode").val());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did you see OP's Edit :) ?