# How to find the selected value from the dropdown using Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="awe-ajaxdropdown-field">
    <input data-notr="1" name="TestFIName" id="TestFIName" class="awe-val" type="hidden" value="7126">
    <select class="awe-display awe-field form-control" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <option value="">--Select test--</option>
        <option value="7172">1000RPM 380PBA all patterns</option>
        <option value="7173">1000RPM low load tight all patterns</option>
        <option value="7141">10pct 2KM noise without krrefend learned mp data</option>
        <option value="7174">1500RPM 230PBA all patterns loose</option>
        <option value="7175">2000RPM 230 PBA all patterns</option>
        <option value="7176">2000RPM low load tight all patterns</option>
        <option value="7179">2500RPM 230 PBA all patterns and continuous random</option>
        <option value="7177">2500RPM pattern misfire no load line</option>
        <option value="7131">2MF_2SF-7003_1_CELL4_20160506_006</option>
        <option value="7128">2MF_2SF-7003_10cStart_CELL4_20160506_003</option>
        <option value="7129">2MF_2SF-7003_4hrSoak1_CELL4_20160506_004</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="7126">2MF_2SF-7003_FIMISFIRE_CELL4_20160506_002</option>
        <option value="7125">2MF_2SF-7003_IGMISFIRE_CELL4_20160506_001</option>
        <option value="7130">2MF_2SF-7003_InGear4hrSoak1_CELL4_20160506_005</option>
        <option value="7142">2YM 10pct offset noise file Feb 2016</option>
        <option value="7168">2YM MF toughness2 219AT SW and fire air rev2 052716</option>
        <option value="7152">3500 higher loads issue</option>
        <option value="7153">4000 rpm low load and 230 MF data</option>
        <option value="7154">4500 rpm 380 pba detection</option>
        <option value="7155">4500 rpm low load</option>
        <option value="7178">drive 600rpm all misfire types OK</option>
        <option value="7157">drive with 10pct noise in cyl3</option>
        <option value="7158">drive with cylinder5 offset noise</option>
        <option value="7160">neutral with 10pct noise in cyl3</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            awe.add({
                l:1,type:'add',
                i:'TestFIName',
                url:'/GetData/GetTestName'
                data:{"keys":["parent"
                    "parent"
                    "parent"
                    "parent"]
                    "vals":["ProjectName"
                        "VehicleName"
                        "TestModeName"
                        "testRange"]},
                pars:{ keys:[],

                    vals:[]},
                e:1});
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

How to find the selected option here using Jquery.

Comment: from jQuery:  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of a dropdown in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978328/get-the-value-of-a-dropdown-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="awe-ajaxdropdown-field">
  <input data-notr="1" name="TestFIName" id="TestFIName" class="awe-val" type="hidden" value="7126">
  <select class="awe-display awe-field form-control" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <option value="">--Select test--</option>
    <option value="7172">1000RPM 380PBA all patterns</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7126">2MF_2SF-7003_FIMISFIRE_CELL4_20160506_002</option>
    <option value="7125">2MF_2SF-7003_IGMISFIRE_CELL4_20160506_001</option>
    <option value="7130">2MF_2SF-7003_InGear4hrSoak1_CELL4_20160506_005</option>
    <option value="7142">2YM 10pct offset noise file Feb 2016</option>
    <option value="7168">2YM MF toughness2 219AT SW and fire air rev2 052716</option>
    <option value="7152">3500 higher loads issue</option>
    <option value="7158">drive with cylinder5 offset noise</option>
    <option value="7160">neutral with 10pct noise in cyl3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
alert($(".awe-ajaxdropdown-field select").val());
```

Comment: I am using @(Html.Awe().AjaxDropdownFor component, so I cannot add any id to it.

Comment: I wanted to know in the existing html code how can I get selected option from jquery

Comment: <div class="col-md-3" id="testFIName">
        <label for="TestFIName">FI Test:</label>
        @(Html.Awe().AjaxDropdownFor(x => x.TestFIName).Parent("ProjectName").Parent("VehicleName").Parent("TestModeName").Parent("testRange").Url(Url.Action("GetTestName", "GetData")).CssClass("form-control"))
      </div>

Comment: Is this the only select element on the page?

Comment: Check the updated answer. I removed some options to keep it short, but it shows how you can get it with your existing HTML. Here's a demo also: https://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/31vy9pm6/1/

Comment: No I have couple of dropdowns like this on the page. Can I specify id in your solution

Comment: Can you give this `<div class="awe-ajaxdropdown-field">` an `ID`? Or wrap another `<div>` around it and give that an ID?

Comment: <div class="col-md-3" id="testFIName">
        <label for="TestFIName">FI Test:</label>
        @(Html.Awe().AjaxDropdownFor(x => x.TestFIName).Parent("ProjectName").Parent("VehicleName").Parent("TestModeName").Parent("testRange").Url(Url.Action("GetTestName", "GetData")).CssClass("form-control"))
      </div>

Comment: This is what I have, can you please suggest how can I add id here to get the id for the class="awe-ajaxdropdwon-field"

Comment: Can you add a `<div>` around that?