# Can I use option:selected without knowing the element ID ahead of time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a drop-down (select) column.  When the select's selected option changes, I need to run some validation.  I've got the `change` event firing fine, but I can't figure out the syntax I need to use to get the selected option.  Usually, this is [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist) with this:

```
$("#someDropDownId option:selected").text();
```

I can construct the drop-down's ID at runtime, but for the life of me can't figure out how to get the selected text.

```
var rowId = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var selectId = rowId + '_Description';
//selectId is the ID of the select element, how do I get the selected value now??
```

I've tried all manner of combinations, for example, `$("selectId option:selected").text();`, but I can't figure it out.  Is it possible, and if so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly just use the `on()` method:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
    var selectedOptionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
});
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NW75w/).

Or, more simply:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
    var selectedOptionText = $(this).find('option').eq(this.selectedIndex).text();
});
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NW75w/1/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the event handler you can do `$(this).val();`

or `$(this).find("option:selected").text();` for the text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("selectId option:selected").text()` do `$("#selectId").val()`