# How to get the selected text instead of value in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the user selected texts for my dropdown menu.

I have

```
   var selectMenu=document.createElement('select');
            selectMenu.className='menu';

        for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){

           var option=document.createElement('option');
               option.className='option';
               option.innerHTML=array[i].name;
               option.value=array[i].id;

            selectMenu.appendChild(option);
         }

         $(selectMenu).change(function(){

           //i want to get the selected text here

           //I know I could get value by using $(this).val()
           //but not sure how to get the selected text here.

         })
```

I have google the issue and all I found are like

```
$('#menu option:selected).text().
```

Are there anyways to get what I need? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you have something like

```
<select>
    <option value='1'> SO</option>
    <option value='2'>GOOGLE</option>
</select>
```

you can try

```
$("select").change(function(e){
    console.log($(":selected",this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ykzp7/

Comment: works like a charm! thanks! (need to wait before I give you green.)

Answer (score 1):

try `$('.menu option:selected).text()` instead of `$('#menu` ...