# How to get the selected item of DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

How to get the selected item of DropDownListFor? This is my dropdownlistfor :

```
    <div class="drop-down-list">
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StageId, ViewBag.StagesList as SelectList,new { id="stageOne"})%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StageId) %>
    </div>
```

I tried this but it is not working :

```
<script>
    var e = $('#stageOne').val();
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#StageId option:selected").text();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .. from here : [Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text()
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").val()
```

Comment: Both of them return null :-(