# jQuery get the value from selectbox by its text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have a select box like this:

```
        <select id="year">
        <option value="1">1 Year</option>
        <option value="2">2 Years</option>
        <option value="3">3 Years</option>
        <option value="4">4 Years</option>
        <option value="5">5 Years</option>
        <option value="6">6 Years</option>
        <option value="7">7 Years</option>
        <option value="8">8 Years</option>
        <option value="9">9 Years</option>
        <option value="10">10 Years</option>
        </select>
```

I want to get value of a specific text in jQuery, like "value of 4 Years".  How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicat [Get selected text from dropdownlist using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Comment: $( "#year option:selected" ).text();
// => "4 Years"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using .text() on the selected option. e.g.:

```
$('select option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `filter` method (exact match):

```
$('select option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === '4 Years';
}).val();
```

Using `:contains` selector:

```
$('select option:contains(4 Years)').val();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want the value of the selected option:

```
$('#year').val();
```

If you want a specific option by its text:

```
$("#year option:contains('4 Years')").val();
```

Regards.