# how to pass Kendoui drop down selected value to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

how to bind Kendo ui dropdownlist with model and how to send that selected value to controller with a button Click 
for other operations....

could you please explain be in detail...am a fresher...
thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

**View:**

```
@model Contract
@{
    var vendors = ViewData["Lookups"] as List<Vendor>;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contract", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contractDetailsForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contract</legend>
        <div>
            @{
            Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.VendorId).Name("VendorId")
                .BindTo(new SelectList(vendors, "ID", "DisplayName", "Nothing Selected"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:250px;" })
                .Value(Model.VendorId.ToString())
                .Render();
            }
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="k-button k-button-icontext">
                <span class="k-icon k-insert"></span>Create Contract</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Contract contract)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        contract.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        _repository.Add(contract);
        _repository.SaveChanges();
        //return or redirect to another View ...
    }
    return View("Create", contract);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write select event for the dropdown list like

```
function onSelect(e) {                                                     
       var DropDownval = $("#QuestionType").val();
}
```

put this value in the session or in a variable and pass it to the controller.