# MVC: Get selected text from <Select> using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get the selected item from my dropdown's and use it for validation.

Previously i used:

```
$("#PolicyOrganisation").text());
```

Which worked but then I changed my dropdowns's to the below(loaded from database rather than hardcoded):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="diagnosticMode" class="control-label col-xs-2">Policy Organisation:</label>
    <select id="DD1" name="PolicyOrganisation">
        <option value="-1">Select</option>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.PolicyOrgs)
        {
            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

And my JQuery Validation too:

```
 //Validation for Dropdown      
    var platform1 = $('#PolicyOrganisation option:selected').text();
    var Valid1 = (platform1 !== 'Select')
    if (!Valid1) {
        $('#PolicyOrganisation').css({
            "border": "1px solid red",
            "background": "#FFCECE"
        });
    }
```

I found this method through searching about this question..
[Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)

But the new versions don't work? Can anyone suggest why this might be?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you not use @Html.DropDownListFor()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` with jquery unobtrusive validation?

Answer (score 2):

'PolicyOrganisation' is not an id it is name attribute Please use 'DD1' instead of 'PolicyOrganisation'

```
var platform1 = $('#DD1 option:selected').text();
    var Valid1 = (platform1 !== 'Select')
    if (!Valid1) {
        $('#DD1').css({
            "border": "1px solid red",
            "background": "#FFCECE"
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I had overlooked this. unfortunately its still not working for me tho (my textbox validation works so i know jquery is working)