# Get a List of the Selected Values in a ListBox

Tags: jquery, listbox

There's already a question with a ton of votes for getting the selected value from a dropdown using jQuery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery).

That answer almost works for a listbox, but if multiple values are selected, the result is a single string with all the values concatenated. This is not useful. I need a collection (list, array, whatever) of the text values for each selected option.

At the moment I'm thinking I'll use most of the answer from that other question, but without the `.text()` at the end, and then iterate through the matches. Better ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can take multiple selected **text** by iterating loop as mentioned below.

```
$('#f1').click(function(){    
   var rr = []; 
   $('.selectpicker :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
        rr[i] = $(selected).text(); 
    });
    alert(rr);
});
```

OR  if you want to using it's **value** then simply write.

```
$('.selectpicker').val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/re8tevoc/9/)**

Comment: Yes, It will take all selected option from your dropdown.

Comment: Simply using .val gets me exactly what I want, as in this case the text and value for each option is the same

Comment: Sometimes .val() is returning an array of strings, which is what I want, and other times it is returning an array of DispHTMLOptionElement. Seems random.

Comment: Can you show me example where it is show `DispHTMLOptionElement` in your example?

Comment: Not consistently, no. Seems random. This code `var select = $( '#SelectedItemIds' ); var fields = select.val(); var fields2 = $( '#SelectedItemIds' ).val();` usually produces arrays of strings for both, but occasionally one or the other comes out as objects. It only did it the first few times, so I'm hoping there was something wrong with the environment and it's fine now. If it happens again I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below :

```
var selectedVal= []; 
$('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
   selectedVal[i] = $(selected).text(); 
   alert(selectedVal[i]);
});
```

[Here is Tutorial and example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-the-value-of-selected-option-in-a-select-box-using-jquery.php)

Comment: upvote for the tutorial, but the rest of the solution is the same as the one already posted

Comment: ya..i think this is the way to get selected value. hope you got solution.