# how to get dropdown lists text jquery

Tags: jquery, html.dropdownlistfor

```
var colDdl = $('#ColumnSelection').text();
var filterDdl = $('#FilterOptions').text();
```

Above is my code where I am trying to get the text of the selected dropdown list item. If i use the `.val()`, I get the value(1,2,3 etc). How do I get the text. Above code gives me null in the respective variables colDdl and filterDdl.

Comment: check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery

Comment: `var colDd1 = $('#ColumnSelection option:selected').text();` should do well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var colDd1 = $('#ColumnSelection option:selected').text();
var filterDdl = $('#FilterOptions option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope this will help you

```
var colDdl =  $("#ColumnSelection option:selected").text();
var filterDdl = $("#FilterOptions option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="ColumnSelection">
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

In script side

```
var colDdl = $("#ColumnSelection option:selected").text();
```

you can apply same method in

```
var filterDdl = $('#FilterOptions option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This, This will help you...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gd').click(function(){
       alert($('#cars').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='cars' name="cars" multiple>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button id="gd">Get Value</button>
```

Using val() you get the values of the selected options, if you use multiple drop down list you will get the result in array.