# Yii2 Put 'id' attribute in <option> tag of <select> tag

Tags: php, html, select, yii2

I need to put an `id` attribute in my **first** `<option>` tag only. I tried:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'supplier_id')->dropDownList(
                    $static + $listData, 
                    ['prompt'=>'', 'id' => 'supplier']);
```

But its `id` is not in the `option` tag but it's in the `<select>` tag. So it goes (as I inspect element in my browser):

```
<select id="supplier" class="form-control" name="Purchase">
```

And here's my first `<option>` tag:

```
<option value="/IAOY/web/index.php?r=contact%2Fcreatecontact">Add New Supplier</option>
```

As you can see it doesn't have an `id` attribute (I'm fully aware that my code is wrong).
Is there a way to put an `id` attribute in **first** `<option>` tag only, using Yii2?

Comment: how could you have same id in all options. No there is no way and doesn't make sense either

Comment: sorry, I edited my question. that's why I need to put an `id` because my modal needs an `id` to get the value of that specific `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

You would be better running some jquery to get the value of the selected option and passing that to your modal. There are some useful methods in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery). If you're using bootstrap modal you can do this in the `.modal('show')` event of the modal dialog.