# Get selected id from drop-down list (select box) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching for a way to get the `id` from a drop-down list option, when it is selected. I have found the following:
[Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery?rq=1)
And tried to change the accepted answer to:

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").id;
```

But when I `alert()` it, it gives me "undefined". Is there a way to get the id using JQuery?

Comment: `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").attr('id')`

Comment: @Mr_Green Isn't that the same as what I wrote? isn't `.id` the same as `.attr('id')`?

Comment: @julianavar nope.. there is difference. always use console to check whether you doing it correct or not. :)

Comment: @julianavar. Its not same. you are using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) style and not pure [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp) style.

Comment: @julianavar Don't get confuse between jquery's object and javascript's DOM object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected")` returns a jQuery object which does not have the `id` property so, you can use .attr() to get id of the element

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").attr('id');
```

Comment: @julianavar `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected")` is a jQuery object which does not have the `id` property, but the selected `option` element have the `id`(as far as I understood that exists and OP wants that value)....

Answer (score 2):

Get the id using `.attr()` or `.prop()`:

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").prop('id')
```

or

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").attr('id')
```

and if you want to use pure javascript then:

```
var obj=document.getElementById("myId").options[document.getElementById("myId").selectedIndex];
alert(obj.id);
```

Don't mix the jquery object with js property like `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").id`.