# using jQuery, I need to capture the correct variable from change event when selecting from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, select, jquery-mobile

I need to capture the text variable selected from id

```
<select name="city" id="selectedCity" data-native-menu="false" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="#">-- Select City --</option>
  <option id="atl" value="#tiera">Atlanta</option>
  <option id="aus" value="#tierc">Austin</option>
  <option id="bal" value="#tiera">Baltimore</option>
  <option id="bos" value="#tiera">Boston</option>
</select>
```

problem: no matter which option is selected, I always get the last var listed, in this case I always get Boston.

```
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("selectedCity").reset();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var cityInfo = $("#atl").text();
  var cityInfo = $("#aus").text();
  var cityInfo = $("#bal").text();
  var cityInfo = $("#bos").text();

  $("#selectedCity").change(function(){

      $("h1").text(cityInfo);
      });
});
```

Comment: Of course, because your last var declaration have that value - remove city info var lines completely... Btw, your intention is to redirect user after his choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, you don't need to capture `cityInfo` four times. By doing that, the value of `cityInfo` will always be Boston because that's what you are setting it to, regardless of the change.

What you really want it something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectedCity').change(function() {
    console.log($('#selectedCity option:selected').text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the selected option.

As you may see there is a lot of [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery) to do it.

In your case, why not try something like this

```
$("h1").text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/969yzfob/)

Hope it may helps you