# drop down select value is show default

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have select option value drop down looks like

```
<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero" >
    <select id="ddlCompare1" class="dropdown" onChange="javascript:CompareLoantype(true);" >
            <option value="jumbo">Conv</option>
            <option value="fha" selected >FHA</option>
            <option value="va">VA</option>
            <option value="usda">USDA</option>
    </select>                                    
</div>
```

all four option value have single interest rate

```
<input name="Compare_interest_rate" id="Compare_interest_rate" class="txt"   type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" style="width:75%" />%</p>
```

four  option value  have four default value

FHA value- `<?php echo $interest_FHA_default; ?>`

VA value-`<?php echo $interest_VA_default;?>`

USDA value- `<?php echo $interest_USDA_default;?>`

CONV  value- `<?php echo $interest_CONV_default;?>`

how to show four value depends on drop down select ?  if user select FHA  value need FHA  value .. please any one give me idea ?

Comment: From what i can understand, you want to show the selected drop down value in your input tag. For that you can get the dropdown object **document.getElementById('dd1Compare1');** in your onChange function and then get the selected value.

Comment: yes if  i select FHA   i want show value textbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected text from drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onChange function do this:

```
function CompareLoantype() {
    var dd = document.getElementById('ddlCompare1');
    var selectedText = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text; // or .value if you want to show value
    document.getElementById('Compare_interest_rate').value = selectedText;
}
```

Comment: how can pass my value  in this script ?