# CheckValue of a drop down in Jquery

Tags: jquery, dropdown

If this code checks the value of a radio button, what do I change if I need to check the value of a drop down box?

```
var checker= jq('input[name="radioname"]:radio:checked').attr("val");
```

Comment: probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selecter = jq('select[name="selectname"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :)

```js
$(':radio[name="sex"][value="male"]').prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Sex : <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male 
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" checked="checked">Female
```