# Change the value of label with change in drop-down value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the value of label with change in drop-down value using jQuery but its not working. Please help me fix this.

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br/>
<label id="label"></label>
<br/>
```

```js
$("label").val("150.000.000");
$(("#myselect").val()).on('change', function() {
    if ($("#myselect").val() == '1') {
        $("#label").val("150.000.000");
    } else  {
        $("#label").val("350.000.000");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector attached to the `change` event is incorrect, you need to provide the `id` of the element as a string, not the value of the element itself. Also, `label` elements don't have a value you need to use `text()` to change them, and you can use `this` within the `change`handler to refer to the `select` element. Try this:

```js
$("label").text("150.000.000");
$("#myselect").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $("#label").text("150.000.000");
  } else {
    $("#label").text("350.000.000");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<br/>
<label id="label"></label>
<br/>
```

You can even shorten the JS code to this:

```
$("label").text("150.000.000");
$("#myselect").on('change', function() {
    $("#label").text(function() {
        return $(this).val() == '1' ? "150.000.000" : "350.000.000";
    })
});
```

Comment: It definitely should, as you can see from the snippet. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, just a question, is there a difference between `$(this).val()` and `$("option:selected", this).val()`. I saw the latter one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery) and assumed its more preferred.

Comment: `$(this).val()` accesses the `value` property of the `select` directly. `$("option:selected", this).val()` looks for the selected `option` element within the `select` and gets the value from that. The first version is simpler, better practice and faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all values in an array and can use value to compute index of value to be selected.

Following snippet depicts the same:

```js
var data = ["150.000.000", "350.000.000", "550.000.000", "750.000.000"];

$("#myselect").on("change", function() {
  var selectedVal = $("option:selected",this).val();
  var newValue = data[parseInt(selectedVal)-1];
  $("#label").text(newValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<br/>
<label id="label"></label>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("label").text("150.000.000");
  $("#myselect").on('change', function() {
    if ($("#myselect").text() == '1') {

      $("#label").text("150.000.000");

    } else {

      $("#label").text("350.000.000");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tested what `$("#myselect").text()` actually returns?

Comment: Exactly, and that's unfortunately why it won't work.

Comment: That's not working though... Change to `3`, value goes to `350`. Change back to `1` and it stays on `350`