# Search box placehoder text should change when an option is selected from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a drop-down list with this code:

```
  <select class="selectpicker" id="select_designatfirst" title="Select Designation">
  <?php foreach ($this->hierarchydisp as $val) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $val['hierarchy_id']; ?>" ><?php echo $val['hierarchy_name'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

So far I am getting this output.

[image]

I am trying to change the search box placeholder text per the drop-down list.

The search box looks like this:

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empSearch"  placeholder="Search Employees">
```

The placeholder text in the search box should be: `Search Company Admin` when user selects Company Admin from the select box.

Comment: You need to the code you're getting stuck with into the question as an [mcve].  Read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask).  What you have posted doesn't even qualify as a question so far.

Comment: By "label" do you mean the placeholder text? Or a label tag that is not shown in the code? It is not completely clear what you are asking.

Comment: @UselessCode the placeholder text of the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a `change` event to the select box. In it you [grab the text from the selected option](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) and set the `placeholder` attribute on the search box.

```
var select_designatfirst = $('#select_designatfirst'),
  empSearch = $('#empSearch');

select_designatfirst.on('change', function () {
  empSearch.attr('placeholder', 'Search ' + select_designatfirst.find(':selected').text());
});
```

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/hb5xqwf3/)

That said, unless the search box is far removed from the drop down it probably isn't necessary to do this. As long as the drop down is appropriately labeled so its function is clear, it should be obvious that it is limiting your search results to only a certain employee type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should add an event handler to the selectbox onchange event like so:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('empSearch').placeholder = this.value" class="selectpicker" id="select_designatfirst" title="Select Designation">
<?php foreach ($this->hierarchydisp as $val) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $val['hierarchy_id']; ?>" ><?php echo   $val['hierarchy_name'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

The above example will put the value of the dropdown (in your example the id) as teh placeholder of the textbox. If you want to use the text value you can for instance use the technique mentioned here:

[Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)

Comment: i did the same as above, nothing change.

Comment: Using `.value` would make the placeholder text display the `hierarchy_id`, I think he probably wants to display the `hierarchy_name` instead.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in the last paragraph :)

Comment: @UselessCode you are right sir, i want to display hierarchy_name as a  current placeholder.

Comment: @robba Ah. Didn't see that, only looked at the code.