# jquery select not displaying value

Tags: jquery, select

I have a radio button which when clicked is displaying select box below so I could choose an option. My problem is that I can't get the value from select box. It returns as null. I guess problem is that it should have another change event in it. Can you tell me how to put another change event inside this change event?

Select box:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="radio clip-radio radio-primary">
          <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="vertical" value="Pricelist" />
            <label for="radio3">
            Pricelist
            </label>
     </div>
     <div id="Pricelist" class="desc">
         <div class="form-group">
           <select class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic" name="pricelist" id="pricelist_select">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select pricelist</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
           </select>
     </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery

```js
//Displaying select box when type radio button is clicked
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input[name=vertical]").on( "change", function() {
                     var test = $(this).val();
                     $(".desc").hide();
                     $("#"+test).show();
                     $("#pricelist_select").val();
                     $('#pricelist_select').trigger("change");
                    alert($("#pricelist_select").find(":selected").val());
                    $.cookie('pricelist_select', $("#pricelist_select").val());
                } );

            });
```

CSS for hiding select box

```
.desc { display: none; }
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button, insert the RENDERED HTML of the php since this is NOT a PHP question. Then click tidy and you have a [mcve]. Also you need to include the cookie JS

Comment: You should not get any value from a disabled select. You are not posting enough of the code that gives you the problem - here is how to get the text in a simpler way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery

Comment: I have edited my qestion, so maybe now it's more clear what is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$(this).val()` instead or `$('#pricelist_select').val()` if you are not inside the scope of the `#pricelist_select` element:

```js
$('#pricelist_select').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic" name="pricelist" id="pricelist_select"> 
  <option value="" disabled>Select pricelist</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I like you're solution and I have tried it, but I always get the last value. I don't understand why? How can I debug that?

Comment: Any chance you have 2 `select` elements? Otherwise it makes no sense at all (if you use the exact solution I gave).

Comment: Yes, I have three of them on same page. I thought id is refering to exact select.

Comment: Yes. My next question is if they each have unique id. Can you create a working example in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: From what I see everything works great in your jsfiddle. what is the problem?

Comment: I always get first value from select box, no matter what I choose. I don't understand that. Is it possible that some other part of the code is preventing it from getting the value? If ID is unique than it should be OK?

Comment: I just used the example in your jsfiddle and I get the correct result (I get 25 if I choose 25, 15 if I choose 15, etc)

Comment: Yes, but in my actual code, I always get same number, no matter what I use. Maybe is something else that is bugging me.

Comment: I think it's something else. I asked a jsfiddle not with my code, but with your code (a jsfiddle that **shows the problem**) Not a working one :)

Comment: Yes I did.  This is what's reported:

Comment: Yes I did. <anonymous> http://portal.drezga.hr/pma/calculation/calculation_wizard.php:1314:50
 n.Callbacks/j http://portal.drezga.hr/pma/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:27131
 n.Callbacks/k.fireWith http://portal.drezga.hr/pma/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:27949
 .ready http://portal.drezga.hr/pma/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:29781
 K

Comment: It looks like you have errors in your javascript (however I'm not sure what exactly the error is. It's impossible to read it this way).

Comment: OK, I will just keep trying. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Budimir - your JSFiddle does not look or work like the example in your question. Please create a [mcve] that shows the actual issue instead of confusing those who come after by accepting an "answer" that is not fixing your actual problem

Comment: @mplungjan according to the question - the answer is correct. If the question was regarding the javascript errors - I agree, the answer is not correct. But it isn't the case. The answer gives the exact solution to the problem the OP mentioned.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question. Maybe now is more clear what my problem is.

Comment: I don't see your checkbox in the example, and please remove all the PHP from your code. Keep only the output (the generated html).

Comment: Ok, I have edit my question and added HTML code with radio button and select box. Also added CSS class which is hiding that select box until radio is checked. Now I need to figure out how to get value from select box when radio is clicked and displayed and select has been selected?