# Get selected value from drop down which is populated from a database

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I want to get the selected `SystemID` from my drop down menu which is populated by a database. I have named the drop down`"data3"`

Drop down from database is all working, it is displaying all the SystemIDs from my table.

Code below:

```
<select id ="data3" style="position:relative; top:-70px; left: 3.6%;" 
name="data3" class="btn btn-light btn-sm dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT SystemID FROM MyTable ORDER BY 
        SystemID";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value=\"\">" . $row['SystemID'] . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
  </select>
```

How do I get the selected value from that drop down? I have tried doing

```
var data3=$("#data3").val();
```

But this returns nothing

Comment: try this $("#data3 option:selected").val();

Comment: for value use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery..This question is duplicated

Comment: @ImranAhmadShahid So `var data3=#("#data3 option:selected").val();` or `var data3=$("#data3 option:selected").val();`

Comment: Your answer does not work @ImranAhmadShahid It returns nothing

Comment: use jquery selector $, by mistake # was inserted, I have edited

Comment: Tried that, same problem

Comment: you have to give value in <option value=\"\"> too,

Comment: Oh How can I do that?

Comment: [Here's a MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) about the HTML-tags `<select>` and `<option>`.

Comment: you can try this <option value=\""+ $row['SystemID']+"\">

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but in my case, i'm getting my drop down populated from a database.. ?

Comment: Just echo the value you want in the correct place. You already have code to echo the values from the database (the text for each option). Something like: `value=\"" . $row['TheDbColumnToUseAsValue'] . "\"`

Comment: @ImranAhmadShahid - In PHP, you concatenate strings using `.`, not `+`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm abit confused now

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for refresh. I haven't work in php since 4 years :P

Comment: Your PHP-code generates HTML code. You're looping through a result set from a database query and are creating new `<option>`-tag for each row. In that code, you're already outputting the `$row['SystemID']` as the text for the option. Now output the same thing in the `value=""`-attribute for the option. You could also simply remove `value=\"\"` completely. Then you would get the option text as the value.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok so I did `echo "<option value=\"" . $row['SystemID'] . "\"</option>";` and now my drop down is not even printing all the systemIDS..

Comment: That's not what I told you to do. Do either `"<option value=\"" . $row['SystemID'] . "\">" . $row['SystemID'] . "</option>"` or `"<option>" . $row['SystemID'] . "</option>"` (which works if the value and the text are the same).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator to check if the value coming from the database match the one from the select and mark it as selected. Please note that you must have a list of all the values of the select/option statement to be able to compare.

`$row['SystemID'] == $value?'selected':''`

```
echo "<option value='".$row['SystemID'] ."' ". ($row['SystemID'] == $value?'selected':'') ."  >" . 
        $row['SystemID'] . 
     "</option>";
```

Comment: Also, when using a ternary operator when you concatenate strings, you usually need to group it with parentheses. `string ' . ($condition ? 'on true' : 'on false') . ' string`. Otherwise, PHP won't know when the `on false` results ends and the rest begins.

Comment: is not fully necessary but added the change for easy reading and identifying the ternary operator. thanks

Comment: _"is not fully necessary"_ - As mentioned in my previous comment, in this context those parentheses are _very_ necessary, or the output will simply be wrong. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/cKYb4)

Comment: you are correct, I use them in Laravel a lot inside {{}} and they are change to <?php echo TERNARY OPERATION ?>