# Unable to get the text of the selected option inside a drop-down "TypeError: selectobject.selected is undefined"

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code, to get the text of the selected option inside a drop-down field:-

```
var selectobject = $("select[id*='ResponsibilitySubCategory']");
var currentsubcat = selectobject.selected.text();
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
"TypeError: selectobject.selected is undefined"
```

Comment: `selected` isn't a property of jquery

Comment: @Vencovsky ok i see , so how i can get the text of the selected option then?

Comment: check [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) and [this](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectobject = $("#myselect :selected");
var currentsubcat = selectobject .text()
```

For an ASP.NET dropdown you can use the following selector:

```
$("[id*='MyDropDownId'] :selected")
```

Comment: but in my case i already have the first selector as `var selectobject = $("select[id*='ResponsibilitySubCategory']");`

Comment: please do a `console.log($("select[id*='ResponsibilitySubCategory']");)` and show me what you see