# How to autofill input text when change form select

Tags: jquery, laravel

I trying to display harga_beli in form input when selecting nama_produk in form select, but form input showing id_produk not harga_beli. I have uploaded view , jquery and controller. How to resolve this issue?

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Nama Produk</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="id_produk" name="id_produk" required>
      <option value="">-- Pilih Produk --</option>
      @foreach($produk as $produk)
         <option value="{{ $produk->id }}">{{ $produk->nama_produk }}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Harga Beli</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="harga_beli" name="harga_beli" placeholder="Harga Beli" readonly>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#id_produk').on('change', function() {
   $('#harga_beli').val($('#id_produk').val())
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $produk = Produk::all();

    return view('pembelian.create', compact('produk');
}
```

Comment: IF you want to show the selected text from dropdown in readonly input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

use some data-value in option field

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Nama Produk</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="id_produk" name="id_produk" required>
      <option value="">-- Pilih Produk --</option>
      @foreach($produk as $produk)
         <option value="{{ $produk->id }}" data-value={{$produk->nama_produk}}>{{ $produk->nama_produk }}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Harga Beli</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="harga_beli" name="harga_beli" placeholder="Harga Beli" readonly>
</div>
```

Edit you jquery as:

```html
$('#id_produk').on('change', function() {
  var input_value = $(this).find(':selected').data('value');;
  $('#harga_beli').val(input_value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

u can also try this one in your view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Nama Produk</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="id_produk" name="id_produk" required>
    <option value="">-- Pilih Produk --</option>
    @foreach($produk as $produk)
       <option value="{{ $produk->id }}" data-value={{$produk->nama_produk}}> 
       {{$produk->nama_produk }}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <label>Harga Beli</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" id="harga_beli" name="harga_beli" placeholder="Harga Beli" readonly>
</div>
```

and jquery code like this

```
$(document).on('change','#id_produk', function() 
{
  var selected =$('#id_produk option:selected').val();
  $('#harga_beli').val(selected);
});
```