# ajax internet explorer onchange

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer

My ajax script for loading the second select box, works in firefox and chrome, but internt explorers cant handle it. I call the onChange function from my select box and give the value from the select box to the function.

Code:

```
function getXMLHTTP() 
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

return xmlhttp;
}

function getType(categoryName) 
{       

    var strURL="includes/get.php?c="+categoryName+"&sid="+Math.random();
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

                req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (req.readyState == 4) {
                                // only if "OK"
                                if (req.status == 200)
                                    {document.getElementById('type').innerHTML=req.responseText;                        
                                } else {
                                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                                }
                        }               
                }           
                req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                req.send(null);
        }       
}
```

My second question is, is it possible to send the text between the options tag instead of the value in the options tag?

Comment: It is better to use AJAX framework (e.g. jQuery) to handle cross-browser issues. Try not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah but its just this little script nothing more

Answer (score 1):

For your 1st question, I assume your `if (req)` returns false. Which IE version are you using? Try to add debug codes in `getXMLHTTP()` function to start diagnosing the codes. Try this solution provided by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx

I try not to repeat other's answer. Here is the answer for obtaining text in selected option tag : [Getting the text from a drop-down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913/getting-the-text-from-a-drop-down-box)

Comment: i tried to use the solution from Microsoft, but it is still not working. For firefox and chrome everythings works perferct, but in IE 9 or 8 it isnt working.

Comment: Didnt work with jquery before, I could try it but I have no idea how to implement the current code in jquery