# Obtaining the text from a drop-down box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, client-side-scripting

This gets the value of whatever is selected in my dropdown menu.

```
document.getElementById('tester').value
```

I cannot however find out what property to go after for the text that's currently displayed by the drop down menu. I tried "text" then looked at W3Schools but that didn't have the answer, does anybody here know?

For those not sure, here's the HTML for a drop down box.

```
<select name="tester" id="tester">
    <option value="1">A skill</option>
    <option value="2">Another skill</option>
    <option value="3">Yet another skill</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: for jQuery checkout [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist). For pure JavaScript check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913/getting-the-text-from-a-drop-down-box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var tester = document.getElementById('tester');
var text = tester.options[​​​tester.selectedIndex].innerHTML​;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/447f6/)

Comment: Thank you that is what i was looking for awesome nice work and very fast return!

Comment: An `option` DOM object does have a `text` property, so `.text` should work here too: `var text = tester.options[​​​tester.selectedIndex].text;`

Answer (score 1):

[Text looks good to me - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUMHq/)

```
$('#tester').on('change', function(){
    console.log($('option:selected', this).text()); 
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('tester');
var selected_text = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
```

(this is untested, but your answer should be similar to this)