# DropDownlist Selected text when Submit button click in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to get the selected text in Angular when I select an item in Dropdownlist.

Please Note that I want to get the **text** without any `onchange` event in Dropdownlist. I use query selector to get the value of Dropdownlist and event is button and button inside form tag. Here is my code

```
const ddldepartment = target.querySelector('#ddldepartment').value;
const ddldesignation = target.querySelector('#ddldesignation').value;
```

Here I get the value like 1 and 2 not getting the text. and I am using

```
<form (submit)="PostEmployee($event)">
```

and

```
PostEmployee(event) {
    const ddldepartment = target.querySelector('#ddldepartment').value;
    const ddldesignation = target.querySelector('#ddldesignation').value;
}
```

Here is my HTML Code for the dropdownlist:

```
<select id="ddldepartment" [(ngModel)]="ddldepartment" name='ddlbankcode' style="width: 70%">
    <option value=0>Choose...</option>
    <option class='option' *ngFor="let dept of department" [value]="dept.dept_code">
      {{dept.dept_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

I got value in console. I want to get text. How can I find it?

Comment: can you update your html code?

Comment: Hello Please check I update the dropdownlist HTML

Comment: Try using `innerHTML` property

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947/6080889

Answer (score 1):

You're already using `[(ngModel)]="ddldepartment"`. So you'll already have the selected value in the `ddldepartment` property.

All you need to do is use `[ngValue]="dept.dept_name"`

Like this:

```
<form (submit)="postEmployee()">
  ...
  <select 
    id="ddldepartment" 
    [(ngModel)]="ddldepartment" 
    name='ddlbankcode'>
    <option value='null'>Choose...</option>
    <option 
      class='option' 
      *ngFor="let dept of department" 
      [ngValue]="dept.dept_name">
      {{ dept.dept_name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  ...
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

So in your Class:

```
postEmployee() {
  // This will give you the selected department name text
  console.log(this.ddldepartment);
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-departments-dropdown-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.